# Localizing position of electron in hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen, orbitals

Consider the hydrogen atom, just taking into account the electrostatic force and not magnetism nor spin.

Is it possible to take the wave functions of the energy eigenstates of that hydrogen atom, appropriately weight each one, and then sum them up in order to get something like a Gaussian wave function of position, or at least to localize position into a single narrow range for $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$, such that there is a $99.999$% chance that the electron is in that narrow range?

My surmise is no, since the spherical harmonic angular momentum eigenstates do not look like they could possibly be combined in such a was as to localize the electron within the angular degrees of freedom.

Comment: So something like a Rydberg wave packet - see, for example, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.80.5508

Comment: *the spherical harmonic angular momentum eigenstates do not look like they could possibly be combined in such a was as to localize the electron within the angular degrees of freedom* Yes, they can. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics): “Since the spherical harmonics form a complete set of orthogonal functions and thus an orthonormal basis, each function defined on the surface of a sphere can be written as a sum of these spherical harmonics.”

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what the time evolution of the peak of the Gaussian looks like, in this example?

Comment: No, I haven’t seen that calculation for hydrogen. I don’t know whether it can be done analytically or can only be done numerically.

Comment: The case I would first look for is when the initial state is a delta function (i.e., infinitely tall and narrow Gaussian). Then we’re talking about a Green’s function for the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: seems to me it is not a probable case in nature. See this https://www.nature.com/articles/498009d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is very much possible. The trick is that however they must combine, it must be very subtle and hard to imagine immediately. But it *can* be done. The eigenstates form a complete orthonormal set, hence they can express "any" (with suitable caveats in the scarequotes) initial configuration, and all you have to do to find the expansion is to take inner products: any *bound* state $|\psi\rangle$ will satisfy

$$|\psi\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} \langle\psi_{n,l,m}|\psi\rangle\ |\psi_{n,l,m}\rangle$$

where $|\psi_{n,l,m}\rangle$ are the basis states for each choice of quantum numbers $n$, $l$, and $m$.

What does this look like? Well, if we go to the position basis, so that the states are now represented with wave functions $\psi(r, \theta, \phi)$, it looks as follows: the coefficient in the above is

$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi_{n,l,m}|\psi\rangle &= \iiint_\mathbb{R^3} \bar{\psi}_{n,l,m}(r, \theta, \phi)\ \psi(r, \theta, \phi)\ dV\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \bar{\psi}_{n,l,m}(r, \theta, \phi)\ \psi(r, \theta, \phi)\ r^2 \sin \theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi\end{align}$$

Now suppose that we want the electron localized to a wedge $r \in [r_1, r_2]$, $\theta \in [\theta_1, \theta_2]$, $\phi \in [\phi_1, \phi_2]$. Then you can treat $\psi(r, \theta, \phi) = K$ within the wedge and as $0$ outside it, so you simply limit the bounds of integration accordingly:

$$\langle \psi_{n,l,m}|\psi\rangle = K \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \bar{\psi}_{n,l,m}(r, \theta, \phi)\ r^2 \sin \theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi$$

where the normalizing factor $K$ is equal to $(\text{volume of wedge})^{-1/2}$. Of course, working this out explicitly is likely to be extremely complicated, or one can just calculate the coefficients numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about the possibility, of course, you can do that. Energy eigenstates a Hydrogen atom form a complete basis, just like the eigenstates of any Hermitian operator, and thus, they can be linearly combined to obtain any other state-vector, including a Gaussian on a sphere spiked at some particular angular value.

---

For example, in [the documentation of this opensource package for MATLAB](https://www.chebfun.org/examples/sphere/SphericalHarmonics.html), they expand a Gaussian (with $\sigma=0.4$) on a sphere in the basis of spherical harmonics and numerically the compute coefficients, see Section 3.

Comment: Just curious, in the case where we linearly combine the wave functions of the energy eigenstates, to obtain a Gaussian wave packet, how would that spike move in the time-dependent solution?

Comment: @David Presumably, it spreads out. I haven't done the calculation but that'd be my expectation based on general considerations.

Comment: But, does it rotate around the proton, in some way, as it is spreading?

Comment: Again, I haven't done the calculation so I am not comfortable making any predictions. It'd depend on a lot of things, at least naively. Which spherical harmonics are contributing, how much, how do their relative phases change, etc. etc.

Comment: I have tried to find references to this special case, but cannot. Seems like someone must have addressed this, before. If you come across any references, to the time evolution for the Gaussian linear combination of wave functions of energy eigenstates of hydrogen, please let me know and thank you for your responses!

Comment: the time evolution of an energy eigenvalue is just a rotation of the global phase, so you can derive the time evolution of an arbitrary wavefunction if you an decompose it into energy eigenvalues (= orbitals). The energy of each orbital then says how fast that orbital's phase rotates.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Agreed but it'd take some work to visualize how does it look like in terms of the change in the angular position of the Gaussian peak (which would also be spreading out simultaneously and also wouldn't necessarily be remaining a Gaussian with time evolution).

Comment: @DvijD.C. another issue is that you don't actually get to let the wavefunction evolve undisturbed indefinitely. Something bumps your atom -> mass measurement -> the electron picks one orbital.